# how to make social media buttons start only from under a photo/post?

Tags: css

this is the website http://filldevoid.com/test/

i want the social buttons from under the post to start everytime under the photo, not on the right of the photo (cause it does that, where it has enough space)

so like in first photo, not like in second.

what kind of condition or what could i use?

i tryed br and p, adding them into the beginning of the share, or the end of the post.. but with no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element that encases the media share buttons need to have `clear: both` applied to it in your themes style.css .

Add

```
.fballshare{
clear: both;
}
```

to the end of your style.css

Comment: could you please tell me how(the code)? i don't know css or js

Comment: I have edited my answer.